# enum set to string and get sting value when need

Tags: c#, string, enums

I don't know how to do this
I want code like following

```
enum myenum
{
    name1 = "abc",
    name2 = "xyz"
}
```

and check it

```
if (myenum.name1 == variable)
```

how can I do those things?

thanx.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? This is not how enums are used. Your `if` condition doesn't make sense - it would always return `true` if it worked, because `name1` was declared to have `abc` as its value. A useful condition would be `if (var == myenum.name1)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Associating enums with strings in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630803/associating-enums-with-strings-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible.  Enums can only have a basic underlying type (`int`, `uint`, `short`, etc.).  If you want to associate the enum values with additional data, apply attributes to the values (such as the [`DescriptionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx)).

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(this Enum value)
        where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var type = value.GetType();
        var name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
        return type.GetField(name)
            .GetCustomAttributes(false)
            .OfType<TAttribute>()
            .SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public static String GetDescription(this Enum value)
    {
        var description = GetAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>(value);
        return description != null ? description.Description : null;
    }
}

enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("abc")] Name1,
    [Description("xyz")] Name2,
}

var value = MyEnum.Name1;
if (value.GetDescription() == "abc")
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

Comment: why not just enum.ToString("F") ?

Answer (score 5):

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851567/chow-to-use-enum-for-storing-string-constants) what you are doing is not possible. What you could do maybe would be to have a static class full of constants, maybe something like so:

```
class Constants
{
    public static string name1 = "abc";
    public static string name2 = "xyz";
}

...

if (Constants.name1 == "abc")...
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do, maybe you could achieve the same effect by using a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) instead of `enum`s.

Answer (score 0):

This was discuessed here before, but can't find it. Short version: you can't give enum members string values. You can use the member names as the values, but often this isn't what you want. Please [follow this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/archive/2008/03/12/enum-with-string-values-in-c.aspx) for a guide how to use attributes to annotate string values to enum members.

Answer (score 0):

Nice answers here. Elaborating onto the suggested answer is if you would like to rather ***get the enum value given the enum description***. I havent tested this but this might work :

**Enum :**

```
public enum e_BootloadSource : byte
{
    [EnumMember]
    [Display(Name = "UART")]
    [Description("UART_BL_RDY4RESET")]
    UART = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    [Display(Name = "SD")]
    [Description("SD_BL_RDY4RESET")]
    SD = 2,
    [EnumMember]
    [Display(Name = "USB")]
    [Description("USB_BL_RDY4RESET")]
    USB = 3,
    [EnumMember]
    [Display(Name = "Fall Through Mode")]
    [Description("FALL_THRGH_BL_RDY4RESET")]
    FALL_THROUGH_MODE = 4,
    [EnumMember]
    [Display(Name = "Cancel Bootload")]
    [Description("BL_CANCELED")]
    CANCEL_BOOTLOAD = 5,
}
```

Use as follows :

```
foreach(e_BootloadSource BLSource in Enum.GetValues(typeof(e_BootloadSource)))
                    {
                        if (BLSource.GetDescription() == inputPieces[(int)SetBLFlagIndex.BLSource])
                        {
                            newMetadata.BootloadSource = BLSource;
                        }
                    }
```

Note inputpieces is purely a string array and newMetadata.BootloadSource is e_BootloadSource.