# Picker Item Selected Event Raised Multiple Times when using Generic Types

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I have ran into a peculiar one that is halting development on my app. I have a picker that the user can select payment types from (this app doesn't handle payment, its an expenses page). I have pictured this below.

[image: The picker]

Behind the picker is an Enum called `Payment Type`. I have used some code from out and about to convert the enum name to a more pleasing string format (CreditCard -> Credit Card).

References for this:
[enum set to string and get sting value when need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426444/enum-set-to-string-and-get-sting-value-when-need/10426606#10426606)
https://alexdunn.org/2017/05/16/xamarin-tip-binding-a-picker-to-an-enum/

I am using MVVM and databinding to set this picker, here is the property that the picker is binding to:

```
PaymentType _selectedPaymentMethod;
public string SelectedPaymentMethod
{
    set
    {
        var enumValue = _enumHelper.ConvertStringToPaymentTypeEnum(value);//ConvertStringToEnum<PaymentType>(value);

        if(SetProperty(ref _selectedPaymentMethod, enumValue))
        {
            _expenseItem.PaymentType = _selectedPaymentMethod;
            _canCreateExpense = validateForm();
        }
    }
    get
    {
        return _enumHelper.ConvertPaymentTypeEnumToString(_selectedPaymentMethod);//ConvertEnumToString<PaymentType>(_selectedPaymentMethod);
    }
}
```

Before we look at the methods being called, lets have a look at our enum:

```
public enum PaymentType
    {
        [Description("None")] 
        None,

        [Description("Credit Card")] 
        CreditCard,

        [Description("Cash")] 
        Cash
    }
```

So I have an enum helper class which I am using to Convert the enum to a string and back. I found if I put the enum directly into the picker, I was left with poorly formatted text, and if I formatted the text the `set` event was never fired. So I have to convert my enum to a `List<string>` to display it and convert back to process it. Also the enum has a default value of none which I hide from the view, the enum default to 0 so when I call validate I how the property hasn't been set.

Lets now look at the methods I am calling:

```
public PaymentType ConvertStringToPaymentTypeEnum(string text)
{
    foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(PaymentType)))
    {
        PaymentType enumValue = (PaymentType)value;

        if (text == enumValue.GetDescription())
        {
            return enumValue;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

public string ConvertPaymentTypeEnumToString(PaymentType paymentType)
{
    foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(PaymentType)))
    {
        PaymentType enumValue = (PaymentType)value;

        if (paymentType == enumValue)
        {
            return paymentType.GetDescription();
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

This all works well and the app functions properly, take a look at it in action:

[image: The app running on non generic code]

Now, this enum method was hardcoded to 1 enum type, these 2 methods are un-reusable... which I don't want as I might want to use it elsewhere. So once I implemented it here I decided to convert these methods to use generic types, so I could use them with other enums. Lets take a look at what I did.

```
public T ConvertStringToEnum<T>(string text)
{
    foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
    {
        T enumValue = (T)value;

        var enumVal = enumValue as Enum;

        if (text == enumVal.GetDescription())
        {
            return enumValue;
        }
    }

    return default(T);
}

public string ConvertEnumToString<T>(Enum @enum)
{
    foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
    {
        Enum enumValue = (T)value as Enum;

        if (@enum == enumValue)
        {
            return @enum.GetDescription();
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

Now if I call these new methods (notice them commented out earlier), I run into the stupidest most non sensical bug ever. Both methods work and return what I want however the setter gets called again and the methods return default (specifically the first method, ConvertStringToEnum)

Look at how the app now runs....

[image: The app running on generic code]

So when I change my method type to generic, the setter of `ProcessedState` gets called twice.... what?

I have no idea whats going on here and googling didn't seem to help. What in the name of Xamarin is happening?

*note* I am using Prism DryIos for this app, however i strongly doubt it is causing the issue here.

Comment: Why do you first cast to `T` and then to `Enum`? Are you sure there are no exceptions? `enumVal` might be `null` for example, not to mention string values not corresponding to any defined enum value.

Comment: @Haukinger The code wouldn't run properly if I wrote `Enum enumValue = (T)value` and passed `enumValue` to the rest of my function. I guarantee the function is working, I should have shown a gif of debugging. The set method gets called, the correct enum value is set.... and then another set call gets made and the enum is reset to `PaymentType.None`

Comment: @Haukinger I think its an issue with binding, the control is clearly not accept the value in my view model

Comment: The issue was with the second method, enum to string. The enum compare was never executing even if it was correct. I've done this to fix `if (@enum.ToString() == enumValue.ToString())`, doesn't seem great but it works for now. Since my value was never getting set then a new event was raised to reset the value.