# How to convert a number to its enum?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I've declared an enum like so:

```
typedef enum
{
    firstView = 1,
    secondView,
    thirdView,
    fourthView
}myViews
```

My goal is that a `UIButton` will trigger another function with the `uiButton` `sender.tag`and that function will know to convert the integer to the correct view. I'm aware that I can just create an array with the names of the views but I am looking for something smarter than that using the declared enum.

Example:

```
-(void)function:(UIButton *)sender
{
  ...
  ...
  NSLog(@"current View: %@",**converted view name from sender.tag);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the best solution is to actually store the views. You can also use a `IBOutletCollection` to create the array. Declaring an `enum` is just another way to store names.

```
self.views = @[firstView, secondView, thirdView, forthView];

...

button.tag = [self.views indexOfObject:firstView];

...

- (void)buttonTappedEvent:(UIButton*)sender {
    UIView* view = [self.views objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
}
```

PS: converting `tag` into `enum` is trivial, it's just
`myViews viewName = sender.tag`, possibly with a cast `myViews viewName = (myViews) sender.tag`

Comment: I just saw that you gave the same solution I ended up doing. One question, `myViews viewName = (myViews) sender.tag;     NSLog(@"View #: %u",viewName);` will output a number and not the enum name

Comment: @EXEC_BAD_ACCESS True. An enum is just a symbolic name. If you write `int a = 1; NSLog(@"%d", a)`, you don't expect it to output `a`. If you want to log a descriptive name, you have to convert the enum value to a string. There are different ways how to do it - e.g. declaring a second array with names or X-macros. In most situations the integer number is enough because you know what it means.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing it inside a NSMutableDictionary ?

```
NSMutableDictionary *viewList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    [viewList setObject:@"firstView" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
}

...

-(void)buttonTappedEvent:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    NSLog(@"current view: %@", [viewList objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:"%d", tappedButton.tag]]);
}
```

Comment: "I'm aware that I can just create an array with the names of the views but I am looking for something smarter than that using the declared enum."

Comment: Enums are only for ordinal types apparently:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851567/chow-to-use-enum-for-storing-string-constants. What is your ultimate goal, what are you trying to achieve with views and enums? Dynamically load views in certain orders on the iPhone screen ?

Comment: It's a bit more complex than that. Looks like an array is my only option.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is declare it to dictionary for once using dispatch once

```
static NSDictionary* viewList = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        viewList = [NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"firstView",[NSNumber numberWithInt:2], @"secondView",[NSNumber numberWithInt:2], @"thirdView",@"secondView",[NSNumber numberWithInt:3], @"fourthView",
nil];
    });
```

and find with tag like this:

```
-(void)function:(UIButton *)sender
{
  NSLog(@"current View: %@",[viewList objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag]);
}
```