# How to restrict a variable to a fixed set of strings?

Tags: c#

If I want to restrict the values of the spicelevel column in the database to 1, 2 and 3, I could do something like

```
    private enum SpiceLevel
    {
        Low=1,
        Medium=2,
        Hot=3
    }
```

Then in the code I could do `(int)SpiceLevel.Low` to pick 1 as the spice level.

Now what if I have a need where I can only accept "Red Rose","White Rose" and "Black Rose" for the values of a column in the database? What is a graceful way to handle this?

I am thinking of storing them in a config file or constants, but neither is as graceful as enums. Any ideas?

**Update:**

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630803/associating-enums-with-strings-in-c-sharp) worked for me

Comment: Are you looking for a way to enforce this in code, or in your database?  Those are both completely different questions.

Comment: I want to enforce this in c# code.

Comment: Ah.  Create a wrapper object.  In the setter for the value, make sure the new value is valid.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851567/chow-to-use-enum-for-storing-string-constants

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Associating enums with strings in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630803/associating-enums-with-strings-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `property` for this

```
public string[] AllowedRoses = new string[] {  "Red Rose", "White Rose" ,"Black Rose" };
string _Rose = "Red Rose";
public string Rose
{
    get
    {
        return _Rose;
    }
    set
    {
        if (!AllowedRoses.Any(x => x == value)) 
               throw new ArgumentException("Not valid rose");
        _Rose = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on the number of Allowed Rose you might want a HashSet instead.

Answer (score 2):

I can see the following options:

- verify the value in the setter (see for example l4V's answer)
- conceptually, you're thinking about an enum. So you could do the following:

> ```
> enum RoseType { RedRose, WhiteRose, BlackRose };
> ```

and then provide appropriate conversion from this enum to string. Two convenient options how to do it are described here: [Enum ToString with user friendly strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479410/enum-tostring). One is to use a custom Description attribute, and the second (I'd prefer this one) to provide an extension method:

> ```
> public static class RoseTypeExtensions
> {
>   public static string GetString(this RoseType @this)
>   {
>     switch (@this)
>     {
>       case RoseType.RedRose:
>         return "Red Rose";
>       case RoseType.WhiteRose:
>         return "White Rose";
>       case RoseType.BlackRose:
>         return "Black Rose";
>       default:
>         throw new InvalidOperationException();
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

- create a set of constants:

> ```
> public class RoseType
> {
>   public readonly RoseType RedRose = new RoseType("Red Rose");
>   public readonly RoseType WhiteRose = new RoseType("White Rose");
>   public readonly RoseType BlackRose = new RoseType("Black Rose");
>
>   public string Content { get; private set; }
>
>   private RoseType(string content)
>   {
>     this.Content = content;
>   }
>
>   public override string ToString()
>   {
>     return this.Content;
>   }
> }
> ```

As Oskar Berggren correctly pointed out in the comment, `RoseType` should also provide other standard overrides beside `ToString`: `Equals`, `GetHashCode`, `operator==` and `operator!=`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no really good solution. All of them require the database to be "synchronized" with the enum in C#.

Simplest solution:

What you said store the enum values as integers in the database.

Almost as simple but less efficient:

Store the values as strings in the database and convert between string and enum with `anEnumVar.ToString()` and `Enum.Parse` (or any of the other parse methods in Enum).

Complex but flexible:

Have a sort of enum in the database: a table with string values and ids and then use foreign keys to that table where you want to save the enums. This allows you to either select/update/insert using the numeric value or the string value (via a join).

It also maintains integrity as it is not possible to store an integer which has no corresponding enum value.

The downside is the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mapping of string to enum with `Dictionary<string, SpiceLevel>` to associate the string to the Enum. Wrap them in a class.

You could also use a Decorator attribute `[Name("Red Rose"] Low=1,` and get that from the enum itself, but that involves reflection, which has some performance issues, especially when iterating through enum values to find the one with the matching attribute.

```
public static class Spice
{
    public enum Level
    {
        Low = 1,
        Medium = 2,
        Hot = 3
    }

    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Level> spices = new Dictionary<string, Level>{
        { "Red Rose", Level.Low },
        { "White Rose", Level.Medium },
        { "Black Rose", Level.Hot },
    };

    public static bool TryGet(string spiceName, out Level spiceLevel) => spices.TryGetValue(spiceName, out spiceLevel);

    public static string SpiceName(Level target) => Enum.GetName(typeof(Spice.Level), target);
}

/// <summary>
/// Some tests to validate it works. This could be a unit test or just in a console app
/// </summary>
public class SpiceTest
{
    public void VerifyBlackRoseIsHot()
    {
        string subject = "Black Rose";
        Spice.Level expectedSpice;

        // Here's the ease of use. Pass a string, get an enum and whether it's a valid string
        var result = Spice.TryGet(subject, out expectedSpice);

        //Some Assertion from a unit test library
        Assert.True(result, $"Unable to find spice '{subject}', when it should exist");
        Assert.True(Spice.Level.Hot.Equals(expectedSpice), $"The returned spice '{ Spice.SpiceName(expectedSpice) }' was not the value 'Hot' as expected");
    }
}
```