# How can i restrict the values of a variable?

Tags: java, list, variables, methods

```
Profissional prof = new Profissional(null, null);
List<Profissional> profissional = new ArrayList<Profissional>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true) {
    String comando = sc.next().toUpperCase();

    if (comando.contentEquals("RP")) {
        String categoriaPro = sc.next();
        if(!categoriaPro.equals("Medicina")) {
            System.out.println("Categoria inexistente");
        }else if(!categoriaPro.equals("Enfermagem")) {
            System.out.println("Categoria inexistente");
        }else if(!categoriaPro.equals("Auxiliar")) {
            System.out.println("Categoria inexistente");
        }
        String nomePro = sc.next();
        prof.NomeVerificacao(profissional , nomePro, categoriaPro);
    }


    if(comando.contentEquals("SAIR")) {
        break;
    }
}

for(Profissional pro : profissional) {
    System.out.println(pro);
}
```

This is my main.

```
public class Profissional {
    private String nome;
    private String categoria;

    public Profissional(String nome, String categoria) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }
     // getters and setter

    public void NomeVerificacao(List<Profissional> profissional, String nome, String categoria) {
        if (profissional.isEmpty() == true) {
            profissional.add(new Profissional(nome, categoria));
        } else {
            int i = 0;
            for (; i < profissional.size(); i++) {
                if (profissional.get(i).nome.equals(nome)) {
                    System.out.println("Profissional existente.");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (i == profissional.size()) {
                profissional.add(new Profissional(nome, categoria));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i'm trying to create Object, in this case is a professional of an hospital.
What is done is that can't have more that one professional with the same name, but what i can't figure it out is how to restrict the value of "categoriaPro" to "Medicina", "Enfermagem" and "Auxiliar".
And if it isn't one of them i print the messagem "Categoria inexistente".
but it isn't working.
can any body help??

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: method names should be written in camelCase, i.e. `NomeVerificacao` should be `nomeVerificacao`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict the variable to certain values checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18263403/8568784).

Also you need to have an AND statement after the conditions and only if they all fail print "Categoria inexistente"

```
if(!categoriaPro.equals("Medicina") && !categoriaPro.equals("Enfermagem") && !categoriaPro.equals("Auxiliar")) {
    System.out.println("Categoria inexistente");
}
```

The above checks if it is not any of them.

Comment: That's true, but it will add to the list anyway!

Comment: how do i reset the main without running the list.add()?