# How to localize .NET control properties in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I am trying to give access to `Chart` control's properties through `PropertyGrid`. I'd like to localize it. Is that possible without writing another class, that will mimic most of this control properties and have my custom property display names and descriptions?

P.S.
I know that it is not a good idea to give user "full control" over a UI control through `PropertyGrid`, but it's not my idea ...

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7398740/23354

Comment: I know of a way to localize my custom classes, there are a lot of articles here on SO and other places. I am asking if there is a way to localize (to a single language actually) existing classes, which I can't change/rewrite. Like I wrote already in a question, in this particular case, I want to give access to build in .NET Chart control.

Comment: ah, you probably want `TypeDescriptionProvider` then, but: it is quite a lot of work