# How do I add a resource as the description attribute of a dependency property for localisation

Tags: vb.net, localization, attributes, dependency-properties

I have a dependency property in a custom control which has the following attribute to enable the property to appear under a specific category in the properties viewer with a relevant description.

```
<Category("Vtl Button Images"), Description("Add an image of your choice or leave blank to utilise the default image supplied.")>
Public Property SaveImage As ImageSource
```

Now I would like to localise the description element of the attribute so I added a resource string to the project and attempteted to reference it like so.

```
<Category("Vtl Button Images"), Description(My.Resources.ImageDescription)>
Public Property SaveImage As ImageSource
```

However this throws an error telling me that a constant expression is required.  I get the same error if I try and create a constant set to a resource.

So is it possible to localise the description element of attributes like this and if so how?

Comment: Subclass `Description` to take a key (eg `"SaveImage"`) then in the code there use that as a key to look up and return the localized text.  Attributes are meta data compiled into the assembly, so trying to swap out text directly based on locale wont work.

Comment: @Plutonix  Many thanks, I've stumbled across a c# example of doing something along these lines, Not the easiest of things to follow in it's current guise but I try translating it and see where I get to from there.  I assume thought that there would still be a resource at the back of it that gets translated?

Comment: [This?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7398740/1070452)  yes, as per `TODO: lookup from resx`  That answer is a little confusing because it is implementing a localized Category and DisplayName too

Comment: To say It's a little confusing would be to put it mildly, however it does provide a starting point from which hopefully I can work.

Comment: It is using the  base class to store the localized text.  When the object contain that decorated prop is created, rather than "My Description", it looks up the xlation for that and passes it to the  base class