# How to set string in Enum C#?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I want to create string `ENUM` in c#.

Basically i wan't to set form name in `Enum`. When i open form in main page that time i want to switch case for form name and open that particular form.
I know `ENUM` allows only integer but i want to set it to `string`.
Any Idea?

Comment: Enums can't be strings, Enums are always integral values. You can use the Enum class to get the name of an enum value as a string but you won't be able to use spaces etc.

Comment: Enums in .NET are value types and must be based on a integer value (byte, int, long etc.).

Comment: you want to know which page should load according to enumaration ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125891/why-doesnt-c-sharp-support-string-enumerations

Comment: possible duplicate of [Associating enums with strings in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630803/associating-enums-with-strings-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
private IddFilterCompareToCurrent myEnum = 
(IddFilterCompareToCurrent )Enum.Parse(typeof(IddFilterCompareToCurrent[1]),domainUpDown1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

[Enum.parse] returns an Object, so you need to cast it.

Answer (score 18):

Enum cannot be string but you can attach attribute and than you can read the value of enum as below....................

```
public enum States
{
    [Description("New Mexico")]
    NewMexico,
    [Description("New York")]
    NewYork,
    [Description("South Carolina")]
    SouthCarolina
}


public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
{
    FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

    DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
        (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
        false);

    if (attributes != null &&
        attributes.Length > 0)
        return attributes[0].Description;
    else
        return value.ToString();
}
```

here is good article if you want to go through it : [Associating Strings with enums in C#](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/post/2008/01/17/Associating-Strings-with-enums-in-C.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

As everyone mentioned, enums can't be strings (or anything else except integers) in C#. I'm guessing you come from Java? It would be nice if .NET had this feature, where enums can be any type.

The way I usually circumvent this is using a static class:

```
public static class MyValues
{
    public static string ValueA { get { return "A"; } }
    public static string ValueB { get { return "B"; } }
}
```

With this technique, you can also use any type. You can call it just like you would use enums:

```
if (value == MyValues.ValueA) 
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: the problem with such hacks is that they dont give the true benefit of "strong type"-ness of enums. For instance in your case, I will be able to do `bool b = MyValues.ValueA == "someString"`..

Comment: True, but I rarely find this to be problematic. If MyValues.ValueA really is "someString", I'd want it to return true. Strings are a simple example, but it allows more complex types too.

Comment: For complex types which are sealed and have private constructors, this pattern is a good substitute. Not so for other types like `string`s. The issue I posted is simple. How about this: `string a = MyValues.ValueA;` and later, `a = "haha";`.. Basically spoils the idea of an enum.. I agree there are no simple workarounds. Attributes are the best still..

Comment: Great workaround, works for every use case that I need. Love it +1

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if I understood you corectly but I think you are looking for this?

```
   public enum State { State1, State2, State3 };

    public static State CurrentState = State.State1;

    if(CurrentState ==  State.State1)
    {
    //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that enums are the best solution for your problem. As others have already mentionde, the values of an enum can only be integer values.

You could simply use a `Dictionary` to store the forms along with their name like:

```
Dictionary<string, Form> formDict = new Dictionary<string, Form>();

private void addFormToDict(Form form) {
  formDict[form.Name] = form;
}

// ...
addFormToDict(new MyFirstForm());
addFormToDict(new MySecondForm());
// ... add all forms you want to display to the dictionary


if (formDict.ContainsKey(formName))
  formDict[formName].Show();
else
  MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Couldn't find form '{0}'", formName));
```

Answer (score 2):

Either make the names of the `Enum` members exactly what you want and use `.ToString()`,

Write a function like this ...

```
string MyEnumString(MyEnum value)
{
    const string MyEnumValue1String = "any string I like 1";
    const string MyEnumValue2String = "any string I like 2";
    ...

    switch (value)
    {
        case MyEnum.Value1:
            return MyEnumValue1String;

        case MyEnum.Value2:
            return MyEnumValue2String;

        ...
    }
}
```

Or use some dictionary or hash set of values and strings instead.

Answer (score 1):

`string` enums don't exist in C#. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125891/why-doesnt-c-sharp-support-string-enumerations).

Why don't you use an `int` (default type for enums) instead of a `string`?