# Passing enum/ compiled value as a parameter to constructor

Tags: c#, attributes, enums, parameter-passing

At the moment I am writing my own ValidationAttribute for my mvc application.

I have following ValidationAttribute code.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)] 
public class RecordAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{

   public UniqueDataRecordAttribute(string primaryKeyProperty)
   {

   }
}
```

I pass the field name of my primary property as a string to my attribute and make sone validation.
E.g.:

```
[RecordAttribute("CustomerID")]
public class CustomerMetaData
{


}
```

This works for me, but I will run into problems if the name of the primary key will change.

I created a enum which contains the primary key attribute. But when I try to pass it the compiler is telling me:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

I also tried this approach: [Associating enums with strings in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630803/associating-enums-with-strings-in-c-sharp) but the effect is the same.

Is there any chance to pass a enum (or other compiled value) to my attribute?

Thank you

Comment: Why would the name of the primary key change. That sort of thing you fix in place so it doesn't change....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
[RecordAttribute(Keys.CustomerID.ToString())] 
public class CustomerMetaData 
{ 
}
```

That won't work because the string returned by Keys.CustomerID.ToString() isn't a constant.

Instead of an enum could you use a static class of const string fields?

```
static class Keys {
  public const string CustomerID = "CustomerID";
}
```

Then this will work:

```
[RecordAttribute(Keys.CustomerID)] 
public class CustomerMetaData 
{ 
}
```