# Alias to Enums Types C#

Tags: c#, .net

```
public enum eEstado
{
    Active = 3,
    Inactive = 4
}
```

I need to settle diferent names(like alias) to the enum properties. For example, for "Activo", something like "Activo" and others. Also I need to get that String from the value (3, or 4).

Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630803/associating-enums-with-strings-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Mark, indeed, but I'd recommend answer #2.  The top-voted answer is oddly irrelevant.

Comment: And as for the 2nd part of this OP's question, the answer is `((eEstado)3).ToString()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert from an alias to an enum value:

```
public static eEstado AliasToEstado(string alias)
{
    switch(alias)
    {
        case "Activo": return eEstado.Active;
        case "Inactivo": return eEstado.Inactive;
        default: throw new ArgumentException(alias);
    }
}
```

to convert from an enum value to an alias:

```
 public static string EstadoToAlias(eEstado value)
 {
    switch(value)
    {
        case eEstado.Active: return "Activo";
        case eEstado.Inactive: return "Inactivo";
        default: throw new ArgumentException(value);
    }
 }
```

to convert from an int value to an alias:

```
int value = 3;
string alias = EstadoToAlias((eEstado)value);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to understand what exactly you are asking but I think this will help:

You can have multiple names with the same value on an `enum` like:

```
public enum Status
{
  Undefined = 0,
  Active = 1,
  Inactive = 2,
  Default = Active
}
```

and you can parse from a string with

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Status status = Status.Default;

    string new_status = "Inactive";

    status = (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), new_status);

    Console.WriteLine(status.ToString());
    // prints "Inactive"

    status = (Status)1;
    Console.WriteLine(status.ToString());
    // prints "Active"

}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use any name in enum but you can not use enum for string

like

```
public enum eEstado
{
// its an valid enum
    Activo = 3,  
    Inactivo = 4
}
```

and for use enum like string

you can convert it in string

exm.

```
strinf s=eEstado.Activo.ToString();
```

then

```
if(s==eEstado.Activo.ToString())
{
  // do sumthing
}
```

in this the value of 's' will not 3 . it will 'Activo'
i think it will helping for you

welcome for your thank's

best of luck

Comment: This addresses neither supporting multiple string values nor converting an int into a string.  (no, comparing each possibility of the enum to a string representation doesn't count)

Comment: is you want 'Activo' by 3 ?