# How to change name of Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, enums

I have enum

```
enum TestEnum : byte
    {
        one = 1,
        two = 2
    }
```

I am getting name of enum by

```
var x = Enum.GetName(typeof(TestEnum), TestEnum.one);
```

Now here i am getting `x = 'one'`

I want to get 'TTT' (TTT is any custom name)by setting some attribute on Enum.
So that when i call

```
var x = Enum.GetName(typeof(TestEnum), TestEnum.one);
```

I can get `x = 'TTT'`

I tried with 'DisplayNameAttribute' but not getting.

Comment: "I tried with 'DisplayNameAttribute' but not getting." - so show what you tried. (You'd need to write code to retrieve the attribute for the right value, of course...)

Comment: You can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630803/associating-enums-with-strings-in-c-sharp - the first one is no good, but some of latters are going to fit nicely

Comment: this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799370/getting-attributes-of-enums-value

Comment: @Jone Skeet : Can show me how it use with DisplayName