# How to use enum item name which contains space?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, enums

How to use enum item name which contains space?

```
enum Coolness
{
    Not So Cool = 1,
    VeryCool = 2,
    Supercool = 3
}
```

I am getting the Enum item name by below code

```
string enumText = ((Coolness)1).ToString()
```

I don't wont to change this code but above code should return Not So Cool.
Is there any use of oops concept to make this happen?
Here I don't want to change retrieving statement.

Comment: Remove the spaces, they are uncool

Comment: Exactly, it is not possible.to have enum memebers with spaces.

Comment: Maybe you need [enums with strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630803/associating-enums-with-strings-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You could add a `DescriptionAttribute` that contains spaces.

Comment: take a look at this answer in order to add a description to enums and how to retrieve these friendly names: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1415187/1666620

Comment: You could create a class `Coolness` with properties `String Name` and `byte Factor`, `ToString` returns `Name`.

Comment: Related answer on another post - [Can my enums have friendly names?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1415460/465053)

Answer (score 8):

Use [Display attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
enum Coolness : byte
{
    [Display(Name = "Not So Cool")]
    NotSoCool = 1,
    VeryCool = 2,
    Supercool = 3
}
```

You can use this helper to get the DisplayName

```
public static string GetDisplayValue(T value)
{
    var fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

    var descriptionAttributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(DisplayAttribute), false) as DisplayAttribute[];

    if (descriptionAttributes == null) return string.Empty;
    return (descriptionAttributes.Length > 0) ? descriptionAttributes[0].Name : value.ToString();
}
```

(Credit to [Hrvoje Stanisic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099834/how-to-get-the-display-name-attribute-of-an-enum-member-via-mvc-razor-code) for the Helper)

Comment: I tried this way but

    string enumText = ((Coolness)1).ToString()

this output is "NotSoCool"

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099834/how-to-get-the-display-name-attribute-of-an-enum-member-via-mvc-razor-code there is an enum helper you could use. Try that.

Comment: Here I don't want to change this statement code
string enumText = ((Coolness)1).ToString()

Comment: Well, in that case your only option would be to override `ToString` and make it do something like `return EnumHelper.GetDisplayValue((Coolness)1);`

Answer (score 4):

Avoid `space` on your enum

```
enum Coolness : int
{
    NotSoCool = 1,
    VeryCool = 2,
    Supercool = 3
}
```

To get the value in text, try this:

```
string enumText = ((Coolness)1).ToString()
```

If you want a friendly description for each item of enum, try using the `Description` attribute, for sample:

```
enum Coolness : int
{
    [Description("Not So Cool")]
    NotSoCool = 1,

    [Description("Very Cool")]
    VeryCool = 2,

    [Description("Super Cool")]
    Supercool = 3
}
```

And to read this attribute, you could use a method like this:

```
public class EnumHelper
{
    public static string GetDescription(Enum @enum)
    {
        if (@enum == null)
            return null;

        string description = @enum.ToString();

        try
        {
            FieldInfo fi = @enum.GetType().GetField(@enum.ToString());

            DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            if (attributes.Length > 0)
                description = attributes[0].Description;
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return description;
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
string text = EnumHelper.GetDescription(Coolness.SuperCool);
```

Comment: I don't wont this way. Here enumText will be "NotSoCool", but I want "Not So Cool"

Comment: I've edited my anwser, take a look at my edits.

Comment: Yeah you are right this way it will work..
but Here I don't want to change this statement code
string enumText = ((Coolness)1).ToString() though it should give me the desired answer.

Comment: Is it possible to replace description with displayName ?