# How to cast string to class property

Tags: c#, casting, entity-framework-core

I have a model for my database (using efcore to translate between model and database) that contains a string that can be three values.

In order to better control the string values going into the db, I created an enum of sorts (which you can't do in C# so [I followed this model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630803/associating-enums-with-strings-in-c-sharp)).

```
public class MyModelClass 
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public string MyString { get; protected set; }

    public MyModelClass(int id, MyTranslatingType type)
    {
        Id = id;
        MyString = type.Value;
    }

    public class MyTranslatingType
    {
        private MyTranslatingType(string value) { Value = value; }

        public string Value { get; set; }

        public static MyTranslatingType FirstType
            => new MyTranslatingType(nameof(FirstType));

        public static MyTranslatingType SecondType
            => new MyTranslatingType (nameof(SecondType));

        public static MyTranslatingType ThirdType
            => new MyTranslatingType (nameof(ThirdType));
    }
}
```

However, when I try to grab values from the database, I can't just cast them, or use `typeof()` because they are properties and not a traditional enum/type.

I have tried

```
// error saying it can't convert [PropertyInfo][2] to MyModelClass.MyTranslatingType
MyModelClass.MyTranslatingType myType = typeof(MyModelClass.MyTranslatingType).GetProperty("ThirdType");

// error saying it can't convert string to MyModelClass.MyTranslatingType
MyModelClass.MyTranslatingType myType = (MyModelClass.MyTranslatingType)"ThirdType";
```

How can I cast a string of `"ThirdType"` to a property like `MyModelClass.MyTranslatingType.ThirdType`?

In other words, I want `myType` to equal `MyModelClass.MyTranslatingType.ThirdType` for
 `var myType = (MyModelClass.MyTranslatingType)"ThirdType"`

Comment: Do you mean `MyModelClass.MyTranslatingType myType = MyModelClass.MyTranslatingType.ThirdType;`? Your code intent is not obvious.

Comment: @DavidG I have updated it to better explain what I want `myType` to equal (its at the bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cast one type to another: string to MyTranslatingType you need an implicit or explicit cast operator:

```
public static implicit operator string(MyTranslatingType tp) => tp?.Value;
public static implicit operator MyTranslatingType(string value)
{
    return value switch
    {
        nameof(FirstType) => FirstType,
        nameof(SecondType) => SecondType,
        nameof(ThirdType) => ThirdType,
        _ => new MyTranslatingType(value)
    };
}
```

- Note, switch statement is C# 8. you can update to use traditional switch syntax.

Comment: Not sure you need it to be an implicit operator, but I do like the switch expressions, though you should probably state that's only in C# 8, and therefore .NET Core 3.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a factory pattern of sorts. You can do it something like this:

```
public class MyTranslatingType
{
    // A dictionary of methods to get the relevant type
    private static Dictionary<string, Func<MyTranslatingType>> _typeFactory = 
        new Dictionary<string, System.Func<MyModelClass.MyTranslatingType>>
        {
            { nameof(FirstType), () => new MyTranslatingType(nameof(FirstType)) },
            { nameof(SecondType), () => new MyTranslatingType(nameof(SecondType)) },
            { nameof(ThirdType), () => new MyTranslatingType(nameof(ThirdType)) },
        };

    // Method to get the type required
    public static MyTranslatingType GetMyTranslatingType(string type)
    {
        if (_typeFactory.TryGetValue(type, out var getType))
        {
            return getType();
        }

        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(type), $"Cannot get type for {type}");
    }
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
var myType = MyModelClass.MyTranslatingType.GetMyTranslatingType("FirstType");
```

This method is cleaner than yours as we now no longer have a bunch of public static methods to get types.

Here is a full version using `const`s instead of properties:

```
public class MyTranslatingType
{
    private const string FirstType = "FirstType";
    private const string SecondType = "SecondType";
    private const string ThirdType = "ThirdType";

    private MyTranslatingType(string value) { Value = value; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    // A dictionary of methods to get the relevant type
    private static Dictionary<string, Func<MyTranslatingType>> _typeFactory = 
        new Dictionary<string, System.Func<MyModelClass.MyTranslatingType>>
        {
            { FirstType, () => new MyTranslatingType(FirstType) },
            { SecondType, () => new MyTranslatingType(SecondType) },
            { ThirdType, () => new MyTranslatingType(ThirdType) },
        };

    // Method to get the type required
    public static MyTranslatingType GetMyTranslatingType(string type)
    {
        if (_typeFactory.TryGetValue(type, out var getType))
        {
            return getType();
        }

        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(type), $"Cannot get type for {type}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that is cleaner and I think it's close, but the properties need to exist somewhere (I think they would fit better in the `MyTranslatingType` vs `MyModelClass`). Thoughts?

Comment: Wh do the properties need to exist anywhere?

Comment: Because of the `nameof`. If you copy the class you have above into an empty file, it complain that the `FirstType` and `SecondType` do not exist in the context.

Comment: Then make them private constants instead. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

`typeof(MyModelClass.MyTranslatingType).GetProperty("ThirdType")` return a `PropertyInfo`.

To get the value :

```cs
var myType = (MyModelClass.MyTranslatingType)typeof(MyModelClass.MyTranslatingType).GetProperty("ThirdType").GetGetMethod().Invoke(null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

```
// Outer class 
public class Outer_class
{

    // Method of outer class 
    public void method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Outer class method");
    }

    // Inner class 
    public class Inner_class
    {

        private Inner_class(string value) { Value = value; }

        public string Value { get; set; }

        public static Inner_class FirstType => new Inner_class(nameof(FirstType));


    }
}

class Program
{
    private const string Name = "FirstType";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PropertyInfo obj = typeof(Outer_class.Inner_class).GetProperty(Name);

        Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);

        Console.WriteLine(obj.PropertyType);


    }
}
```