# Switch statement when using an Enum Wrapper (Enumeration base class)

Tags: c#, enums, wrapper

Am using this mechanic here from official Microsoft docs because I need certain functionality that such a wrapper for enums can provide (ability to give enum values a different ToString() name):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types

However I am stuck on how to restore the ability to use those enums in switch statements.

With the exact code from the example, the following code says "A constant value is expected".

```
    var a = CardType.Amex;
    switch(a)
    {
        case CardType.Amex:
            { } break;
    }
```

Have tried "readonly static" as well. Const cannot be applied due to those being instances.
Is it true that there is no way to have `switch()` on any custom type in C#?

Comment: You can't (without crutches, which will take away all the benefits). `Switch` can only work with constants and you have objects, that can't be constants. If you can introduce some kind of backing enum (the real enum) for the wrapper, then you can try to play with cast operators.

Comment: @Serg Hmm, this is quite a pain., I'm not caring about performance by the way. Just the neatness (clean code) of the Switch statement.

Comment: Ok, should have scrolled further down over there - this solution worked perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/630817/1695537 It uses an attribute on normal enums so that switch() is unaffected but the attribute allows additional information. For strings there even was an attribute available already ("Description")...

Comment: Without the language support, building java style enums is too annoying. With attributes, I'd then build some kind of static metadata cache so you aren't using reflection al the time.