# How to get a list of all SQl Data Types on c#?

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

Is there any way to get some list of all Sql Data Types on c#?

I know that we have a Enum called SQlDbType which contains all Sql Data Types, but can we convert an Enum to an array of strings?

I only want to get some list with all Sql Data Types, instead of writing them one by one and adding them into my array of strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Enum to String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483794/convert-enum-to-string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enum to an array of strings is pretty easy:

```
var names = Array.ConvertAll((SqlDbType[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(SqlDbType)),
                             type => type.ToString());
```

or using LINQ:

```
var names = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SqlDbType))
                .Cast<SqlDbType>()
                .Select(x => x.ToString())
                .ToArray();
```

Or more pleasantly using my [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) library, either as an array or (more efficiently) an immutable list:

```
string[] names = Enums.GetNamesArray<SqlDbType>();

IList<string> namesList = Enums.GetNames<SqlDbType>();
```