# Converting Enum for use in a class

Tags: c#, enums

Below I have a piece of code I have been working on for quite sometime:

```
 enum SavingsIndicator
 {
   OKSavings,
   GoodSavings,
   GreatSavings,
 }

static void Main(string[] args)
{

 foreach (string line in gdsLines)
        {

            Match m = Regex.Match(line, @"^(?<date>[^|]+)\|.*Processed\s+(?<locator>[^.]+)\.{3}.*?Savings\s+found:\s*\$(?<savings>\d+\.\d+)\s*\(\s*(?<percent>\d+\.\d+)\s*%");
            if (m.Success)
            {
                Savings s = new Savings();
                s.Prefix = string.Empty;
                s.GDSDate = m.Groups["date"].Value.Trim();
                s.GDSLocator = m.Groups["locator"].Value.Trim();
                s.GDSDollarSavings = decimal.Parse(m.Groups["savings"].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                s.GDSPercentSavings = decimal.Parse(m.Groups["percent"].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                gdsSavings.Add(s);
                gdsTotalSavings += s.GDSDollarSavings;
                gdsTotalPercentage += s.GDSPercentSavings;
 if (s.GDSDollarSavings >= 500)
                {
                    s.Prefix = SavingsIndicator.GreatSavings;
                }
                else if (s.GDSDollarSavings >= 100 && s.GDSDollarSavings < 500)
                {
                    s.Prefix = SavingsIndicator.GoodSavings;
                }
                else
                {
                    s.Prefix = SavingsIndicator.OKSavings;
                }
            }

        }
        foreach (var savings in gdsSavings.OrderByDescending(savingsInstance => savingsInstance.GDSDollarSavings))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(savings.ToString());

        }
    }
   }
```

Below is the class that I have for this to work:

```
class Savings
{
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public string GDSDate { get; set; }
    public string GDSLocator { get; set; }
   public decimal GDSDollarSavings { get; set; }
   public decimal GDSPercentSavings { get; set; }

   public override string ToString()
   {
       return Prefix + "\nDate: " + GDSDate + " \nPNR Locator: " + GDSLocator + " \nDollar Savings: $" + GDSDollarSavings + " \nPercent Savings: " + GDSPercentSavings + " % " + "\n";
   }
}
```

The problem I am having is where I have the prefixes. I want those enumerated values to be in the Prefix variable of my class, but I can't convert my enumerated values to a string. Is there a way to successfully convert this into a string, or is there another way to go around this?

Comment: Why not just do `Enum.ToString();`?

Comment: Take a look at ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483794/convert-enum-to-string

Comment: Wow. Talk about a total brain fart...Thanks @austinwernli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of two things.

1) Just call `.ToString()` on the `enum` value which will convert it to a string with the exact same value as what you named the `enum`, so `OKSavings` becomes `"OKSavings"`.

2) Create a method `public string Format(SavingsIndicator e)` that returns a pretty string describing the enum.

Answer (score 0):

How about writing an Extension Method:

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string AsString(this SavingsIndicator self)
    {
        switch(self)
        {
            case SavingsIndicator.OKSavings:
                return "OKSavings"
               case GoodSavings:
                return "GoodSavings"
               case GreatSavings:
                return "GreatSavings"
        }
        return string.Empty
    }
}
```

In Addition your other Medhod has to be modified:

```
            {
                s.Prefix = SavingsIndicator.GreatSavings.AsString();
            }
            else if (s.GDSDollarSavings >= 100 && s.GDSDollarSavings < 500)
            {
                s.Prefix = SavingsIndicator.GoodSavings.AsString();
            }
            else
            {
                s.Prefix = SavingsIndicator.OKSavings.AsString();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

> or is there another way to go around this?

One can add an `Attribute` to enums and then extract them at runtime. One can also create custom attributes with even more information.

Here is my example from my blog article [Using Extended Attributes](http://omegacoder.com/?p=28) which uses the built in `System.ComponentModel`'s [`Description`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) attribute.

**Example**

```
public enum EPortalErrors
{

  [Description("Internal programming error")]
  InternalError,

  [Description("Invalid request Xml: Reset XSLT.")]
  InvalidXmlSentIn,

}
```

**Static method to extract the description text:**

```
/// <summary>If an attribute such as is on an enumeration exists, this will return that
/// information</summary>
/// <param name="value">The object which has the attribute.</param>
/// <returns>The description string of the attribute or string.empty</returns>
public static string GetAttributeDescription( object value )
{
    string retVal = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
           (DescriptionAttribute[])fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes
           (typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        retVal = ( ( attributes.Length > 0 ) ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString() );
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
     //Occurs when we attempt to get description of an enum value that does not exist
    }
    finally
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(retVal))
            retVal = "Unknown";
    }    

    return retVal;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var msg = EPortalErrors.InternalError.GetAttributeDescription();

// Result "Internal programming error" assigned to msg.
```

See my blog article as mentioned for an example on how to create custom attributes to add even more info.