# Get the value of the enum that I used as parameter in my function

Tags: .net, vb.net, enums, tostring

For example:

```
Enum parameter1Choices
 choice1
 choice2
End Enum

Function sampleFunction(parameter1 as parameter1Choices)
 return parameter1
End Function
```

So if I use the above function like this

```
sampleFunction(parameter1Choices.choice1)
```

I am expecting that it will return `choice1` as `string`

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483794/convert-enum-to-string) and it says that I should use `Enum.GetName`, some said `.ToString`. How do I use that?

Comment: Yeah, already tried it. It return 0. :( I'll try again on using enum.getnames

Comment: `Enum.ToString()` call `GetNames` method internally. So your custom method `sampleFunction` doing exactly same job as `ToString`. What is the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the answer is

```
Function sampleFunction(parameter1 As parameter1Choices) As String
    Return [Enum].GetName(GetType(parameter1Choices), parameter1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `ToString`:

```
Function sampleFunction(parameter1 As parameter1Choices) As String
    Return parameter1.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It seems that using `parameter1.ToString` is much slower compared to `.GetName` it is based [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17034624/2947415)

Comment: You didn't mention that this was speed critical in your question. The difference between them is unlikely to make any difference unless you are calling this 1000's of times. Even then the difference is in the milliseconds

Comment: Yeah, mine is not speed critical. I just thought that maybe I could bring it up here. Thanks! Your's is much straightforward.

Comment: A quick and rough speed test reveals that ToString takes roughly `0.0011ms` per call and GetName takes roughly `0.0006ms` per call

Answer (score 0):

If speed is a big issue the you might try looking the value up in a dictionary

```
Public Enum ParameterChoice
    None
    FirstChoice
    SecondChoice
End Enum

Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class ChoicesLookup
    Private Shared _enumLookup As Dictionary(Of ParameterChoice, String)
    Shared Sub New()
        _enumLookup = New Dictionary(Of ParameterChoice, String)
        For Each choice As ParameterChoice In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(ParameterChoice))
            _enumLookup.Add(choice, choice.ToString())
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetChoiceValue(myChoice As ParameterChoice) As String
        GetChoiceValue = _enumLookup(myChoice)
    End Function

    'prevents instantiation
     Private Sub New()
     End Sub
End Class

Imports System.Text
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

<TestClass()> Public Class UnitTest1

    <TestMethod()> Public Sub TestMethod1()
        Assert.AreEqual("FirstChoice", ChoicesLookup.GetChoiceValue(ParameterChoice.FirstChoice))
    End Sub
End Class
```