# Retrieve enum name as string

Tags: vb.net, enums

How can I retrieve the name of a enumeration as string? I know you can get the integral value, but this is not what I would like.

I searched the `www` but it didn't show any good samples.

I made a example class to proper show what I require.

```
Class test

    Public Property PipeEndTreatment As PipeEndTreatmentEnum
    Public Enum PipeEndTreatmentEnum
        SetOn
        SetIn
        Offset
        OffsetFlush
    End Enum

    Private Sub TestEnumNameValue()


        PipeEndTreatment = PipeEndTreatmentEnum.SetOn

        Dim StringValue As String
        StringValue = "SetOn" ' This value needs to be generated from the PipeEndTreatment property


    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: `StringValue = PipeEndTreatment.ToString()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Enum to String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483794/convert-enum-to-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `ToString()`, e.g. `PipeEndTreatmentEnum.SetOn.ToString()`.

Here's another way in case you like longer ways:

```
[Enum].GetName(PipeEndTreatmentEnum.SetOn.GetType(), PipeEndTreatmentEnum.SetOn)
```