# select base on enum parameter without swich case?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, enums

consider we have this table, as you can see there's a string field we keep state of article

ArticleState can be New,Draft or Published

```
USE [test]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Article](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [ArticleState] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Content] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
)

GO

INSERT INTO Article VALUES (1,'New','title1','this is a test');
INSERT INTO Article VALUES (2,'Draft','title2','this is a test');
INSERT INTO Article VALUES (3,'New','title3','this is a test');
INSERT INTO Article VALUES (4,'Published','title4','this is a test');
GO
```

and we have this enum

```
public enum ArticleStateEnum
    {
        [EnumDescription("Draft Articles")]
        Draft = 10,

        [EnumDescription("New Articles")]
        New = 20,

        [EnumDescription("Published Articles ")]
        Published = 30,
    }
```

how can we select articles based on ArticleState?
I mean what can I write instead of ???????????????????????????????

```
    // GET: Articles
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      var result=  GetArticlesByState(ArticleStateEnum.Draft);
        return View(result);
    }
    public void GetArticlesByState(ArticleStateEnum nse)
    {

        var articleList = db.Articles.Where(x => x.ArticleState ==  ??????????????????????????????);
    }
```

Comment: Why havn't you saved the enum as a int in the db? You could just have saved 10, 20 or 30, and then used `var articleList = db.Articles.Where(x => x.ArticleState == ArticleStateEnum.New);`

Comment: As an aside, storing the state as an `INT` in the database makes more sense, as that's what the enum values are. As even more of an aside, if you're going to store them as string, based on your values you should use `VARCHAR` instead of `NVARCHAR` as there's no unicode values - you're just taking up twice the number of bytes by storing them as unicode..

Comment: @Martin databse designed by others, I have to code based on existed database and project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can't change the database representation, you can just call get the string value with `ToString`:

```
public void GetArticlesByState(ArticleStateEnum nse)
{
    string stateText = nse.ToString();
    var articleList = db.Articles.Where(x => x.ArticleState == stateText);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`Enum.GetName(typeof(ArticleStateEnum), nse)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Either like:

```
public void GetArticlesByState(ArticleStateEnum nse)
{
    var articleList = db.Articles
         .Where(x => x.ArticleState == Enum.GetName(typeof(ArticleStateEnum), nse));
}
```

or like:

```
public void GetArticlesByState(ArticleStateEnum nse)
{
    string state = Enum.GetName(typeof(ArticleStateEnum), nse);
    var articleList = db.Articles.Where(x => x.ArticleState == state);
}
```

Note that this solution would work even with `int` value (as long as the value matches an enum value):

```
public void GetArticlesByState(int nse)
{
    string state = Enum.GetName(typeof(ArticleStateEnum), nse);
    var articleList = db.Articles.Where(x => x.ArticleState == state);
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're keen on `Enum.GetName` rather than just calling `ToString`? (In the `int` version, just casting to `ArticleStateEnum` and calling `ToString` would work.) Note that I suspect the first form *won't* work as I wouldn't expect LINQ providers to be able to recognize `Enum.GetName`.

Comment: The reason why was mostly because of the `int` version, and because I believe that's what this function is for. I suspected the same for the first form, which is why I added the second one. I have nothing to say against `ToString`, this is just an alternative. Also, `Enum.GetName` won't throw an exception as casting would if the value doesn't match, it will just return `null`

Comment: No, casting won't throw an exception either. `ToString()` will return the numeric value.

Comment: Well right, I thought it would. Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: @DaisyShipton apparently, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17034624/7831383) seems to say `Enum.GetName` is faster than `ToString` as `ToString` internally calls `Enum.GetName`. And [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31742218/7831383) uses `nameof(MyEnum.EnumValue)`

Comment: Interesting. I'd still use `ToString()` for the simplicity, unless the performance of that part was actually critical. (In the context of a database lookup, I doubt it would be noticeable at all.)