# How to get items of enum in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, enums, razor-pages

I want to create a select option in Razor pages from Enum object Description

This is my code:

```
<div class="dropdown-box">
    <select id="type-select">
        @foreach (var item in Enums.OrderStatus)
        {
            <option>@item</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

and the enum:

```
public enum OrderStatus
{
    [Description("در انتظار تایید")]
    PendingForAccept = 0,

    [Description("تمام شده")]
    Finished = 1,

    [Description("لغو شده")]
    Canceled = 2,

    [Description("رد شده")]
    Rejected = 3,

    [Description("تایید شده")]
    Accepted = 4
}
```

How can I extract items descriptions of this enum to string

Comment: [Convert enum to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483794/convert-enum-to-string)

Comment: `<select asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<OrderStatus>()"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099834/how-to-get-the-display-name-attribute-of-an-enum-member-via-mvc-razor-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of code that does it.

```
public static string ExtractDescription<T>(T enumVal) where T : struct
{
    var type = enumVal.GetType();
    if (!type.IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(enumVal)} must be an Enum", nameof(enumVal));
    }

    var memberInfo = type.GetMember(enumVal.ToString());
    if (memberInfo.Length > 0)
    {
        var attributes = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(attributeType: typeof(DescriptionAttribute), inherit: false);

        if (attributes.Length > 0)
        {
            return ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;
        }
    }

    return enumVal.ToString();
}
```

Usage:

```
var s = ExtractDescription(OrderStatus.PendingForAccept)// s is "در انتظار تایید"
```